# Flutter button filters

Tags: button, flutter, text, filter, icons

I am trying to work out what is the best way to achieve something similar to the attached

Currently, I have done it like the below, I am wondering if there cleaner or better way using buttons etc..

```
class GetFilters extends StatelessWidget {
  GetFilters();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      // This next line does the trick.
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.call),
              Text('Afterpay'),
            ],
          )
          ]
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.call),
                Text('Afterpay'),
              ],
            )
          ]
        )
    ]
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add an explanation of what you want to achieve. Your title and description aren't explicit, and the image is not self-explanatory.

Comment: Not sure how much clearer I can make it. I am trying to see if what I have done to produce essentially the same is the best method to do so

Comment: The title of your question is "Flutter button filters", but based on what you are saying you just want someone to help build the layout that is seen on the screenshot? Your issue and objective are not clear.

Comment: you need a `LisView` not `Row`

Comment: @pskink first part is a list view with the rows within it

Comment: and how many items you have in your `ListView`? payment options, categories, what more?

Comment: Payments will be up to 10, categories up 25

Comment: how may items you have in outer `ListView`, not in inner `Row`s

Comment: Just 2 payments and categories

Comment: so you need "reversed" design: outer `Column` with 2 inner `ListView`s - one for payments and one for categories

Comment: and most likely `SingleChildScrollView` on top of everything

Answer (score 0):

For horizontal scrolling you need two different ListView for each section

```dart
class GetFilters extends StatelessWidget {
  GetFilters();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Text('Payment options'),
        ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
            Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Icon(Icons.call),
              Text('Afterpay'),
            ],
          ),
           //More items
          ] 
        ),
       Text('Categories'),
       ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: [
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.call),
                Text('Afterpay'),
              ],
            ),
            //More items
          ]
        )
    ]
    );
  }
}
```

For the buttons I would wrap each item with a GestureDetector like:

```dart
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => {},
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
              child: Icon(Icons.call),
            ),
            Text('Afterpay'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

You could use InkWell instead of GestureDetector in case you wanted to have a material visual feedback when the item is tapped

Also i recommend u to use subjects instead of actions in the widget class name. GetFilters could be called Filters, FiltersSection